# Same DB for multiple stagings

Tags: magento2, database, base-url, staging

I am creating multiple staging servers for my Magento 2 website.

- staging1.mywebsite.com
- staging2.mywebsite.com
- staging3.mywebsite.com

Is it possible to have single database for all 3 of my staging servers? the only problem that I am facing is the base URL.

Previously I had used 1 database for multiple local accounts, database was on network server and all the developers was using same database and it was working fine. But for staging domain name are different, so is it possible to do it for staging?

Comment: No it's not possible as you've mentioned base url varies one another @AsimAli

Comment: Is there any other way around?

Comment: @PrathapGunasekaran that's wrong it is possible.

Comment: have you read this guide? @AsimAli

Comment: https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/config-guide/multi-site/ms_websites.html

Comment: @PrathapGunasekaran why do you say that the base-urls are an issue?

Comment: I guess he's not looking for multiple websites, he's have three different staging servers (instances) with single database. If multi website yes it's possible like multi store and so

Comment: Yes, @PrathapGunasekaran is right, I don't want multi website, I just want multiple staging uses same database, I get it, it is not possible